Getting error on importing Browser Module has already imported insted of commonModule, animationBrower also showing error when p dropdown open
NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; import { Dropdown, DropdownItem, DropdownModule } from 'primeng/dropdown';  interface City {   name: string;   code: string; }   @Component({   selector: 'app-dropdown',   standalone: true,   imports: [FormsModule,DropdownModule,BrowserAnimationsModule],   templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',   styleUrl: './dropdown.component.css',   providers: []    }) export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit{   cities: City[] | undefined;    selectedCity: City | undefined;   ngOnInit() {     debugger;     this.cities = [         { name: 'New York', code: 'NY' },         { name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' },         { name: 'London', code: 'LDN' },         { name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' },         { name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' }     ];   }  }  

core.mjs:6531 ERROR Error: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.     at new _BrowserModule (platform-browser.mjs:1258:13)     at Object.BrowserModule_Factory [as useFactory] (platform-browser.mjs:1282:14)     at Object.factory (core.mjs:3322:38)     at core.mjs:3219:47     at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:866:9)     at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:3218:21)     at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3082:33)     at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1100:40)     at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:42)     at useValue (core.mjs:2854:73)

ERROR RuntimeError: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
    at new _BrowserModule (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:29844:13)
    at Object.BrowserModule_Factory [as useFactory] (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:29868:10) 
    at Object.factory (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3965:32)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3886:35)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:2525:5)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3885:11)
    at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3778:23)
    at injectInjectorOnly (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:2634:36)
    at ɵɵinject (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:2640:59)
    at useValue (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3610:67) {
  code: 5100
}

No output file changes.

Application bundle generation complete. [0.878 seconds]

ERROR RuntimeError: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
    at new _BrowserModule (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:29844:13)
    at Object.BrowserModule_Factory [as useFactory] (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:29868:10) 
    at Object.factory (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3965:32)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3886:35)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:2525:5)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3885:11)
    at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3778:23)
    at injectInjectorOnly (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:2634:36)
    at ɵɵinject (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:2640:59)
    at useValue (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3610:67) {
  code: 5100
}
ERROR RuntimeError: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
    at new _BrowserModule (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:29844:13)
    at Object.BrowserModule_Factory [as useFactory] (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:29868:10) 
    at Object.factory (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3965:32)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3886:35)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:2525:5)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3885:11)
    at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3778:23)
    at injectInjectorOnly (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:2634:36)
    at ɵɵinject (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:2640:59)
    at useValue (eval at instantiateModule (file:///E:/Angular%20off/login-page/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54755:28), <anonymous>:3610:67) {
  code: 5100
}


we want to show data in dropdown

please share the minimal reproducible code if possible a stackblitz or a github repo with the issue replicated!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-pfmzwm?file=README.md
here is the stack bliz url and error is in dropdown component

I found usages of BrowserAnimationModule, when we are working with standalone ( usage of bootstrapApplication ), we need to import the animations using provideAnimations sample below!
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideAnimations(), // <- Changed here
  ],
};

After this I removed all occurrences of BrowserAnimationsModule in the source code.
After that the errors went away!
Stackblitz Demo
